# ClaimsAuthorizationManager's CheckAccess() method invoked 3 times

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, claims

I created a class named AuthorizationManager which derives from ClaimsAuthorizationManager. The CheckAccess() method is invoked three times. Why does it happen? Is it a normal process?

I am using Thinktecture Identity Server v2.

**AuthorizationManager Class:**

```
    public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("\n__________Claims Authorization Manager__________\n");
            var result = base.CheckAccess(context);
            CheckAction(context);
            CheckResource(context);
            CheckClaims(context);
            return result;
        }

        private void CheckAction(AuthorizationContext context)
        {

            var action = context.Action.First().Value;

            Trace.WriteLine("\nAction:");
            Trace.WriteLine(action);
        }


        private void CheckResource(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var resources = context.Resource;

            Trace.WriteLine("\nResources:");
            foreach(var resource in resources)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(resource.Value);
            }
        }

        private void CheckClaims(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var claims = context.Principal.Claims;

            Trace.WriteLine("\nClaims:");
            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(claim.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

**AccountController**

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [ClaimsAuthorize(action: "View", resources: "Profile")]
        public ActionResult Profile()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT/TRACE RESULT:**

__________Claims Authorization Manager__________

Action:
GET

Resources:
[some_domain]/account/profile

Claims:
admin
admin

__________Claims Authorization Manager__________

Action:
profile

Resources:
account

Claims:
admin
admin

__________Claims Authorization Manager__________

Action:
View

Resources:
Profile

Claims:
admin
admin

Comment: "AuthorizationManager which derives from ClaimsAuthorizationManager" Uhh... what? On topic, though, I think we'll need to see the attribute you're using and maybe also the base class.

Comment: I am using the the **ClaimsAuthorize** attribute on the AccountController. And the base class of the AuthorizationManager is the **ClaimsAuthorizationManager**